# Divide sum one day for d-1 by category (Power Bi)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzIhV.png)

I have to divide the value of "Soma de Custo" (D-1) for "Soma de Volume), I'm trying the following dax:

Sum of cost yesterday = CALCULATE(SUM(Agrupar[Soma Custo]),Agrupar[Dia]-1)

This formula returns the same values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gKyw.png)

Any help?

Dax to return the correct value

Comment: Please see [ask].